# Java method to extract start and tail of match string

Tags: java, jsp

I have string variable like below,

```
    String foo = "someStringInPrefix<a....<imgtag/>...</a>";
```

I have to extract a whole anchor tag from foo when it contains '' in it, otherwise not. For example from above example I have to extract,

```
     <a....<imgtag/>...</a>
```

How to do this efficiently in java? I know I need to use substring() and indexOf(). But I am looking for effective way to do. Any help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use regex to solve the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "someStringInPrefix<a....<imgtag/>...</a>";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<a[\\s\\S]*(<imgtag\\/>)+[\\s\\S]*</a>");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(foo);
    while(regexMatcher.find()){
        System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringUtils class:

```
String substring=StringUtils.substringBetween("YOURSTRING", "<a", "</a>");
```

To use StringUtils you need to add apache commons lang jar to your project (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)